# How can i format if condition clause in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to format if condition clause which is long one. In the first part it is like below.

[image: birinci hali]

And then when i apply automatic formatting in eclipse, it becomes following.

[image: ikinci hali]

How can i add rule for formatting condition clause of if in eclipse to format like in the first part ?

thanks.

Comment: This will probably help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601793/how-do-i-modify-eclipse-code-formatting