# Eclipse source formatting issues (lambda method chaining)

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I'm using eclipse as my IDE of choice (or my company's choice) and can't figure out how to adjust the source code formatting settings to make usage of basic lambda expressions on stream not look totally awkward.

For example take a look at the following snippet:

```
final Map<String, FieldInformation> fieldInformations = fieldDescriptions
    .values()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(f -> f.fieldId().fieldName(),
            f -> new FieldInformation(f.fieldId(), f.dataType())));
```

This is the way eclipse decides to format the code (we enforce line breaks at 111 characters). But I want it to look more like this

```
final Map<String, FieldInformation> fieldInformations = fieldDescriptions
    .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.fieldId().fieldName(),
        f -> new FieldInformation(f.fieldId(), f.dataType())));
```

I just can't figure out how to change the line-break or whitespace settings in eclipse to format it this way automatically.

Comment: does it help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601793/how-do-i-modify-eclipse-code-formatting

Comment: When you have worked more with streams the formatting convention of one per line will make a lot more sense.

Comment: @user7294900 No, I know where to find the formatting settings, but I can't figure out the setting that changes the formatting as desired,

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've been working with streams for some time now and don't share your opinion :-) If I use the first formatting I can simply write a loop which takes exactly the same amount of code lines and is easier to read.

Comment: @dpr I suggest you discuss this with those who will maintain your code.  It is not the amount of lines on screen but the readability.   Not having to mentally parse the source to clearly see what belongs together may be more important than you think.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, thanks for your suggestion. Actually I'm maintaining the code and I'm pretty fine with the desired formatting.