# Eclipse Formatter add blank line between code blocks

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I don't see this being asked before but link me if I am wrong. Is there a setting in Eclipse to add a blank line between code blocks such as if statements for Java? Sorry, I am new to using Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

So:

```
//code
if(true){
    //if code
}
//next code
```

would be:

```
//code

if(true){
   //new code
}

//next code
```

Comment: Check this SO thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601793/how-do-i-modify-eclipse-code-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no settings in the eclipse formatter for adding blank lines between code blocks.

The only thing that might help you is to increase the "Number of empty lines to preserve" on the "Blank lines" tab, so that your manually added blank lines will not vanish when reformatting the code:

[image]

Comment: I sort of had a feeling. I was hoping I was dense LOL. Thank you.